# Presta 1.7 update() function in product class -> what does "$return = parent::update($null_values) " do?

Tags: php, prestashop, product, updates, prestashop-1.7

in `update()`function of `Product` class in Presta 1.7 there is a line:

```php
 $return = parent::update($null_values);
...
```

I am not sure what this exactly do, can anyone please explain?

I have a case where there is another class for import products and there is a function
that calls `update()`

```php
 private function _updateProduct($product, array $productData)
    {        
        $product->box_quantity = $productData['product_data']['quantity'] == 0?30:$productData['product_data']['quantity'];
        $product->id_shop_list = $productData['shops'];
        $product->active = 1;
        $product->update();
    }
```

During that update my products descriptions are messing up. Descriptions in languages are being override (ex. English descriptions are disappearing).

Shop has 4 languages versions and is multistore. So in `ps_product_lang` there are 8 raws for one product.

I have noticed that when I comment:

```php
/* $return = parent::update($null_values); */
```

in `update` descriptions are not getting messed during import / update.

Comment: I thing the class which this method exists is extending a parent class having the static update method and the parent class also has some properties which are initialized to Null. this method is updating the parent properties and returning a result. It's hard to answer your question without seeing the code.

Comment: thank you, this update() is in core class/product.php of Prestashop and it's parent is  public function update() in ObjectModelCore - ObjectModel.php - it is used to update object in multilingual context. Maybe my object is missing something and that is messing up the update...
the import class with _updateProduct() function is in custom module class